# Smarty template VS Model view controller

Tags: templates, smarty, mvp

I read that Model-View-Controller has good features which allows programer to modify the scirpt without touching other files http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller
I want to know which one is better for project like this MVC or Smarty?
ie. Does smarty has the same features and can let the programer modify it for my needs? or should I let the progrmer work on it from scratch with MVC?

All thanks for your help in advance >>

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is a template engine， it can help you build view layer to separate the html and php script。 In a sense, Smarty contributes you to achieve the MVC pattern。

MVC is just a pattern， it's not a specific technique.

Comment: Smarty contributes you to achieve the MVC pattern。 - Is this in both old and latest versions of smarty or just the newest one especially when the script is little bit old?